# Thread.interrupt is not called when using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, interrupt

I need `MyThread.interrupt()` to be called when I cancel currently executing task. Why isn't itpublic class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<MyThread> threads = new ArrayList<Main.MyThread>();

    List<Future> futureList = new ArrayList<Future>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread(i);
        futureList.add(executor.submit(myThread));
        threads.add(myThread);
    }
    for (Future future : futureList) {
        if (future != null) {
            future.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    // Calling interrupt directly. It works
    for (MyThread myThread : threads) {
        myThread.interrupt();
    }
    shutdownAndAwaitTermination(executor);

}

static void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
    pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
    try {
        // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
        if (!pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
            // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
            if (!pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
            else System.out.println("Maybe OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
        pool.shutdownNow();
        // Preserve interrupt status
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}

private static class MyThread extends Thread {

    HttpURLConnection connection;

    final int i;

    public MyThread(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() {
        super.interrupt();
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Initialize HttpURLConnection and upload / download data
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called, change it here and see output

```
...
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(i + " interrupted");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
...
```

the problem is that ThreadPoolExecutor uses its own Thread to run your task and it will interrupt this thread not yours. It makes no sense to extend Thread, implement Runnable instead. If you still to use Thread then you can call MyThread.interrupt() directly from MyThread.run()

Comment: Actually I download or upload data on these threads. When I need to stop the process, it would be logical to call `interrupt` on each thread downloading / uploading data and disconnect there. So, I can't just implement `Runnable` because it doesn't have `interrupt`. I updated my question.

Comment: then can you just call your interrupt() directly?

Comment: Of course, I can. I just thought it was redundant. If you mention it in your answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3):

`executor.submit(new MyThread(i))` works because `MyThread` extends `Thread` which implements `Runnable`.

As such, the `run` method is actually executed by one of the 10 threads your started in the thread pool. When cancelling the `Future`, the `interrupt` method of `MyThread` is not executed as it is not the executing thread but *considered* a `Runnable`. Nevertheless, The `interrupt` of the threads started by your pool is called.